# How do I get my iOS game to have custom background

Tags: appstore

Sometimes when you go on the App Store to look at games, some have a custom background, instead of the default white. Does this cost extra money to do? Or do certain conditions for the game have to be met?

Comment: Is this off-topic?

Comment: I think it is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Apple has changed something in the policy your app has to be featured to have a custom background.

That means this is not something that you can just set as a developer, your game has be be selected to be featured for this.